# Indentation in HTML

Tags: html

I want to make indentation like the attached document. I have tried

```
<style type="text/css">
.tab { margin-left: 40px; }
</style>

echo "<strong> Introduction:  </strong>
<p class='tab'>
This is the introduction. This is the introduction. This is the     introduction. This is the introduction. This is the introduction. This is the introduction. This is the introduction. This is the introduction. This is the  introduction. 
</p>";
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GgMTL.png)But the desired output is not obtained. I don't want any separate paragraph. Any help please.

Comment: Sorry, can't understand... what do you want to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give your strong element a float left and some more margin to p element which should be equal or more than the strong element text width.

```html
<style type="text/css">
.tab { margin-left: 100px; }
 strong {float:left;}
</style>

<strong> Introduction: </strong>
<p class='tab'>
This is the introduction. This is the introduction. This is the     introduction. This is the introduction. This is the introduction. This is the introduction. This is the introduction. This is the introduction. This is the  introduction. 
</p>
```